# Creating users outside of using the AccountController and passwords are failing when trying to login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am creating users without using the AccountController, and after the user is successfully created, I go and try to log in with that users email and password and it keeps failing all the time, and I have no idea why it would fail because I am creating the users with the same passwords.

Is there something that I could be doing wrong while creating a user without using the AccountController? and I am also adding the new users to the AspNetUser table

The code is

```
AspNetUser user = new AspNetUser();

user.UserName = ahl.AccountHolderName;
user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
user.PasswordHash = pHasher.HashPassword(ahl.AccountHolderPassword);
user.Email = ahl.AccountHolderEmail;
user.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

HWC.AspNetUsers.Add(user);
HWC.SaveChanges();
```

incase anyone asks why I just don't use the AccountController is because I don't want to always have to rely on that controller.

**EDIT**

Here is the login code that is being called when logging in

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check, if the data is in the database?

Comment: @Nikolaus, yes I have and they are there

Comment: You should probably show your login code...

Comment: @DavidTansey, ok, i will do that now...the login code is in the AccountController and uses that one..One sec..

Comment: Did you try to debug that Method? I think your model would be null.

Comment: @Nikolaus, I have debugged it and the ModelState.IsValid is true, and the result keeps failing

Comment: Are you using the same passwordhasher as the usermanager?

Comment: @Nikolaus, I don't believe so because when creating a user through the AccountController Registration method its using ApplicationUser. So since thats the case, maybe I should just query the table myself and do verification on it and if its successful then let it go into the switch statement

Comment: Why you don't use your own user in the AccountController?

Comment: Can you add the Code where the SignInManager is defined/set? Or is it a parameter to the Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have been using two different values for UserName and Email for newly created user.

```
SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() check `userName` and `Password`, not `Email` and `Password` which you are passing in your code.
```

Change `user.UserName = ahl.AccountHolderName;` code to `user.UserName = ahl.AccountHolderEmail;` when creating user, then this should work.

Comment: Awesome, that was the problem. Thanks for getting that cleared up